# Controller can not be accessed via browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, url

I got this case: when I execute `http://localhost:8080/customer/system/ipaddr` which should access the method in the controller I receive this error message:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

I got a very similar structure for other classes where it's working without any issues. Looking for the error for some time now and I have no idea why it is not working..

If you need any further information just let me know.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(CUSTOMER_SERVICE)
public class CustomerController {

    private CustomerProviderComponent customerProviderComponent;
    private CartRequestComponent cartRequestComponent;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerProviderComponent customerProviderComponent, CartRequestComponent cartRequestComponent) {
        this.customerProviderComponent = checkNotNull(customerProviderComponent);
        this.cartRequestComponent = checkNotNull(cartRequestComponent);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(GET_IP_ADDR)
    public String getIpAddr() {
        List<String> response;
        response = runSystemCommandAndGetResponse(IP_ADDR);
        return new Gson().toJson(response);
    }
```

**Constants:**

```
public static final String CUSTOMER_SERVICE = "/customer";
public static final String GET_IP_ADDR = "/system/ipaddr";
```

Comment: There must be an error that is occuring when you are trying to invoke /customer/system/ipaddr and on error it is trying to take you to some error page. Could you please go to your application logs and copy paste the stack trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I am very sorry. The problem was something totally different. I am deploying these applications in a kubernetes cluster. In the deployment script I simply pulled the wrong image from docker hub due to much copy / pasting..

So the error was this line in the deployment script: 
`image: myrepo/articleservice:1.0.4`

Adding `image: myrepo/catalogservice:1.0.4` to the deployment script solved the issue.

The worst thing was that I had no error logs, but @Praveen E made me having a closer look again, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing your application context over this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/customer/system/ipaddr
```

Usually you will have something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/customer/system/ipaddr
```

Unless you are deploying your app to the root of the server.

Comment: The app is deployed to the root. localhost:8080 points at the application

Answer (score 0):

yup,You can able to call it.Make sure that code is running in you local as well as the method name you are calling is not get duplicated